# Toggle effect not working in UL LI

Tags: jquery

I have this menu item with a submenu. The submenu has five itens and I used jQuery to toggle it down. The problem is that only the first item of the submenu is toggling. Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("ul.menu-body li:even").addClass("alt");
        $('img.menu-head').hover(function () {
            $('ul.menu-body').slideToggle('slow');
        }); 
    });
</script>

<ul>
    ...
    <li id="menu-03">
        <a href="galeria_representacao.php?image=0"><img src="images/representacao.jpg" class="menu-head" onMouseOver="this.src='images/representacao-hover.jpg'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/representacao.jpg'" /></a>  
        <ul class="menu-body">
            <li><a href="galeria_representacao.php?image=0">Dixtal</a></li>
            <li><a href="galeria_philips.php?image=0">Philips</a></li>          
            <li><a href="galeria_biosensor.php?image=0">BioSensor</a></li>
            <li><a href="galeria_biorad.php">BioRad</a></li>
            <li><a href="galeria_leica.php?image=0">Leica</a></li>   
        </ul>
    </li> 
    ...
</ul>
```

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/jTZhG/1/

Comment: Can you link us to a public page with the full code? I suspect this may be an issue with the CSS.

Comment: code here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kamila_m/UKWvs/) and the site itself: [link](http://proelhospitalar.com)